# 'sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string ' in Ruby launching a bash script

Tags: ruby, bash

I have the following line in my Rails app:

```
pid = Process.spawn("casperjs #{path_to_file} '#{params[:page][:url]}' '#{Rails.root}/tmp/' --ignore-ssl-errors=yes", :out => pipe_cmd_out, :err => pipe_cmd_out)
```

If params[:page][:url] contains a single quote, like for example this URL: `http://www.degree33surfboards.com/surf-gear/ultimate-9'-epoxy-sand-.html`

I get this error:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

How can I avoid that to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the argument-list form of `Process.spawn` instead of trying to quote things for the shell.

```
Process.spawn(
  "casperjs", path_to_file, params[:page][:url],
  "#{Rails.root}/tmp/", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes",
  :out => pipe_cmd_out,
  :err => pipe_cmd_out
)
```